# Connecting to VPN connects / disconnects the wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn

I am trying to work from home on company VPN. 
When I connect to my home WiFi (say `home-wifi`), I am able to use it forever, without any problem. 
But, when I connect to VPN,

1. disconnects `home-wifi`
2. Searches for saved `company-corporate-wifi`
3. Connects to VPN for a while

and keeps repeating above three steps.

When I connect to my neighbors wifi, VPN works fine. So what might be going wrong here?
Do I need to replace router, or it must be some configuration problem.

PS: I am using netscelar VPN.

Comment: Your neighbor has a different wireless router, but using your computer.  So upgrade the firmware on your own router to see if that helps. Try connecting by Ethernet to your own router and see if that works.

Comment: "but using your computer" means? Is this really firmware thing? I felt that if the WiFi is working fine without VPN, then we might be missing some configuration.

Comment: You would have use your computer with NetScaler VPN installed to test at your neighbor (unless you installed NetScaler VPN and your credentials on your neighbor's computer (seems unlikely).  So at your location, update the router firmware to see if that is the problem. Also update the wireless driver on your computer.

Comment: If the wireless driver had an issue, it would have given issue with neighbors router as well.

Comment: That could be. Also compatibility can be an issue that surfaces with your router and not with your neighbor's.  What I do in this situation is actually try solutions.

Comment: Compatibility between router and laptop? What does that mean exactly?

Comment: Some wireless adapters may not work with some routers. Seen it happen. So once again, TRY the suggestions.